# How to send json to view with jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, database, laravel

I'm really new to jquery and I need a way to pass data from my Controller to my view. 
I'm getting the data from the database in json via the controller, the data shows in the console, the only thing i'm missing is showing it in the view (in a list or a table).

Route:

```
Route::get('wdays/{task_id}', ['uses' => 'WorkdayController@index', 'as' => 'wday.index']);
```

Controller:

```
public function index($task_id)
{
    $sum = "(select sum(hours) from work_days where work_days.task_id = taskID) as sumHours";

    $wdays = DB::table('work_days')
        ->leftJoin('tasks', 'tasks.id', '=', 'work_days.task_id')
        ->where('work_days.task_id', '=', $task_id)
        ->where('work_days.status', '=', 0)
        ->select(DB::raw("work_days.wday_id as id,
        work_days.description as description,
        work_days.hours as hours,
        work_days.week as week,
        work_days.task_id as taskID,
        $sum
        "))
        ->get();

    return ['wdays' => $wdays];

}
```

jquery:

```
    $.getJSON('wdays/' + data.id, function (wdays) {

        $(wdays).each(function (key, value) {

            console.log(value);

        });

    });
```

This is what I get from the console.log:

```
{wdays: Array(1)}
        wdays: Array(1)
            0:
                description: "test"
                hours: "1.0000"
                id: 2338
                sumHours: "1.0000"
                taskID: 1881
                week: "2019-01-01"
            __proto__: Object
            length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to return like this in controller function:

return Response::json(['wdays' => $wdays]);

Comment: I get error in the console if I use return Response (internal server error).

Comment: did you tried using toArray() method after get on query??

Comment: and return as return response()->json(['wdays' => $wdays]);

Comment: Ok found a solution. The problem was in the jquery not the controller. 

`var wdays = $("#wdays_table");
wdays.empty();

Comment: I declared a var before the .each function and then I was able to access the values.